# Code Igniter -> attach email

Tags: php, email, codeigniter

How do you use the email->attach function?

I can't figure what is happen, cos when i put the code for email->attach the mesage came in blank(the mail body) and there is no attach.

If i remove that code line, everything come back to normal..

thank you

my controller (sendmail.php)

```
<?php

 class Sendmail extends Controller {

      function __construct() {
           parent::Controller();
           $this->load->library('email');
           $this->load->helper('url');
           $this->load->helper('form');
           $this->load->library('validation');
      }

      function index() {

           $info = array (
                'nome'  => $this->input->post('nome'),
                'mail'  => $this->input->post('email'),
                'motivo'    => $this->input->post('motivo'),
                'mensagem'  => $this->input->post('mensagem'),
                'anexo' => $this->input->post('upload'),
           );

           $this->load->library('email');
           $this->email->set_newline('\r\n');

           $this->email->clear();
           $this->email->from($info['mail'], $info['nome']);
           $this->email->to('example@mai.com');
     /* $this->email->cc(''); # não é preciso */
           $this->email->subject($info['motivo']);
           $this->email->message($info['mensagem']);
           $this->email->attach($info['anexo']);

           if ($this->email->send() ) {
                echo 'sent';
           }

           else {
            $this->load->view('formulario');
    # show_error( $this->email->print_debugger() );
           }

      }

 }
?>
```

my view (formulario.php)

```
    <?php
    echo form_open_multipart('davidslv/index.php/sendmail');
?>
          <label for="nome">nome</label>
          <input type="text" name="nome" id="nome" required />

          <label for="email">email</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required />

          <label for="assunto">assunto</label>
          <select name="motivo">
               <option value="motivo1">motivo1</option>
               <option value="motivo2">motivo2</option>
               <option value="motivo3">motivo3</option>
          </select>

          <p> <label for="mensagem">mensagem</label>
          <textarea name="mensagem" id="mensagem" rows="8" cols="30" required></textarea>
          </p>

          <label for="upload">documento</label>
          <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" size="18"/>
          <input type="submit" id="enviar" name="enviar" value="Enviar!" />

     </form>
```

Comment: You need to clarify what exactly you are trying to do, attach a JPG/PDF, is the file being uploaded by a user? Is it in a directory like /home/bob/photo.jpg? etc... need more details man..

Comment: also, how about posting the code you have so far so we can see what you're potentially doing wrong.

Comment: Hi, i have edited my post to be more clear. The intention is that any user can send an email to me, but somehow the body(mensagem) is blank and there is no attachment

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can not directly attach a file from the upload field of your form to an email. You can only attach files to your email from your server, so you need to upload the file from the form  with CIs upload library: $this->upload->do_upload() to your server into some directory. the upload library needs to be configured, which file types are allowed etc. if the upload was successful, the do_upload function returns extensive data about where the file is stored. you can use the 'full_path' index from the array to attach this file to the email. then send the mail. after that you may delete the file from your server. Here are some code fragments that might help.

```
$this->load->library('upload');

if($_FILES['upload']['size'] > 0) { // upload is the name of the file field in the form

$aConfig['upload_path']      = '/someUploadDir/';
$aConfig['allowed_types']    = 'doc|docx|pdf|jpg|png';
$aConfig['max_size']     = '3000';
$aConfig['max_width']        = '1280';
$aConfig['max_height']       = '1024';

$this->upload->initialize($aConfig);

  if($this->upload->do_upload('upload'))
  {
    $ret = $this->upload->data();
  } else {
    ...
  }

  $pathToUploadedFile = $ret['full_path'];
  $this->email->attach($pathToUploadedFile);
  ...
  $this->email->send();
  ...
}
...
```

Hope this helped...

Comment: Thanks Richard, your explanation was very good.
Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

> $this->email->attach()
>
> Enables you to send an attachment. Put
>   the file path/name in the first
>   parameter. Note: Use a file path, not
>   a URL. For multiple attachments use
>   the function multiple times. For
>   example:

```
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo1.jpg');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo2.jpg');
$this->email->attach('/path/to/photo3.jpg');

$this->email->send();
```

[Codeigniter Email Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html)

Comment: I've read the documentation, that is easy to do, but when you want a user to send a mail to you, that is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

This is Absolutely right code Please Try

```
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|txt|php|pdf';
$config['max_size']         = '9000';
$config['encrypt_name']     = true;

$image_data = $this->upload->data();
$fname=$image_data[file_name];
$fpath=$image_data[file_path].$fname;

$this->email->attach($fpath);
```

Comment: Hi Friend The above code will solve your problem.The same problem was to me also.this is because the name of file you saved in folder is different as you attched the above code will solve it because it take the correct path of your uploads folder..pls note that the uploads folder should be in root....

Answer (score 1):

step 1:You can not directly attach a file from the upload field of your form to an email. You can only attach files to your email from your server, so you need to upload the file from the form with CIs upload library:

`$this->upload->do_upload()` to your server into some directory.

step 2:

```
 $file=upload file;


 $file_path='uploaded directory on your server(eg:uploads/career)'.$file;
```

step 3:just include

```
$this->email->attach($file_path);
$this->email->send();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late update, but it might be useful. 
It was said twice

> "You can not directly attach a file from the upload field of your form
>   to an email"

. However, this works fine in Codeigniter 3.0

```
foreach ($_FILES as $key => $file)
{
    if ($file['error'] == 0)
    {
        $this->email->attach($file['tmp_name'], '', $file['name']);
    }
}
```

(Though, the email is not sent and no errors are shown, if there are two files with the same name)