# email sending in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to send an attachment from temporary directory?
When I send the mail I am getting the `print_r($_FILES)` as

```
Array ( [file] => Array ( [name] => test.doc 
        [type] => application/msword 
        [tmp_name] => /tmp/php2UaLKE 
        [error] => 0 [size] => 681472 ) 
      )
```

and my error is Unable to locate the following email attachment: **/tmp/php2UaLKE/EasyToEat.doc**

and my statement like:

```
$attachment=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];        
$this->email->attach($attachment);
```

I want to know is it possible to attach an document to mail without uploading that to specified location on the server in codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

I actually just did this... Its got a lil more than you need, but it does just that. Writes a file to a temp directory, then emails it.

```
function send_weekly_report()
    {
        $server_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        if($server_ip != '127.1.1.1')
        {
            $this->load->model('admin_model');
            $this->load->helper('csv_helper');
            $this->load->helper('file');
            //create CSV Array
            $header = array("Sales Rep", "Client", "Action Taken", "Won or Lost", "Action Why", "Current Vendor", "Comp. Cal Program", "Comp. Cal Date", "Notes", "Time");  
            $data = $this->admin_model->load_week();          
            $output = array_merge(array($header), $data);

            $csv = array_to_csv($output);
            $filename = '/tmp/'.time().".csv";
            if ( ! write_file($filename, $csv))
            {
                 $this->load->library('email');
                $this->email->from('donotreply@email', 'Admin');
                $this->email->to('peter@email.com'); 

                $this->email->subject('Weekly Sales Test FAIL!!!!!');
                $this->email->message('Weekly Report Failed!');   
                $this->email->send();
            }
            else
            {
                 //send email
                 $this->load->library('email');
                $this->email->from('donotreply@email', 'Admin');
                $this->email->to('peter@email.com'); 

                $this->email->subject('Weekly Sales Test');
                $this->email->message('Please find the attached report.');    
                $this->email->attach($filename);
                $this->email->send();

                //echo $this->email->print_debugger();                 
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am looking for a code that doesn't need the uploading file to any position.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot one thing:

```
$attachment=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'].'/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];        
$this->email->attach($attachment);
```

The file path is the "tmp_name" of your array (not with "name").
Try this:

```
$this->email->attach($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Here I am getting the mail with attachment name phpa23mPB. But when I save that, I can't open that file.

Comment: Try to move the file to another destination. _move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'path/to/directory/' . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);_. Then you should be able to use the file.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly attach a file from input file field. Please refer to following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628203/3377733