# Email attachment not working fine in hotmail or yahoo codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email-attachments

I have this code:

```
                    $this->load->library('email');
                    $this->email->clear(TRUE);
                    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
                    $this->email->from($edata[0]->eEmail, TITLEWEB);
                    $this->email->to($vendor[0]->cEmail); 

                    $replace = array("[RECEIVER]","[SENDER]","[REQUESTTITLE]","[REFERENCE]","[POREF]");
                    $replacewith = array($vendor[0]->displayName, FNAME." ".LNAME, $purchase[0]->pTitle, $quote[0]->qReference,strtoupper($prorder));
                    $str = str_replace($replace,$replacewith,$edata[0]->eContent);
                    $message = $str;
                    $subjet = str_replace("[SENDER]",FNAME." ".LNAME,$edata[0]->eSubject);
                    $this->email->subject($subjet);
                    $this->email->message($message);

                    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
                    $this->email->attach('resources/uploads/pdfs/'.strtoupper($prorder).".pdf");
                    $send = $this->email->send();
```

Emails are coming properly but the attachment not showing proprly or showing corrupted in hotmail or yaho..
Attachment original size is : 16K
But its showing in email only 332Byte

Can you please tell me what's the issue.. M stuck on this from last 2 days........

[image]

Comment: Please please someone provide solution..........:(

Comment: you can add `$email_respone = $this->email->print_debugger();` after `$this->email->send();` and then `var_dump` the `$email_response` to see the messages that might have been thrown

Comment: possibly it could not locate your attachment file

Comment: maybe this could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383672/code-igniter-attach-email?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 0):

try using `$this->email->clear();`
as using TRUE clears the attachment.