# Codeigniter 3 email attachment from form

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, php-7.1

I have a consultancy controller where users can upload their resume

```
public function consultancy($page = 'consultancy') {
  if (! file_exists(APPPATH.'views/pages'.$page.'.php'))
  {
    show_404();
  }
  $data['title'] = ucfirst($page);


  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
}
```

the view

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align:left;font-size:12px;" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>postconEmail/"method="POST">

               Name <input class="form-control" id="id_name" name="name" type="text" required />
               Phone <input class="form-control" id="id_phone" name="phone" type="text" required />
               From email <input class="form-control" id="id_from_email" name="from_email" type="email" required />
               Subject <input class="form-control" id="id_subject" name="subject" type="text" required />
               Message <textarea class="form-control" cols="40" id="id_message" name="message" rows="10" required></textarea>
            <br>
            <label for="id_resume" class="custom-file-upload"><i class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></i> Resume Upload</label>
            <input class="custom-file-upload" id="filename" type="text" size="35" placeholder="Upload Your Resume"/>
            <input class="btn btn-primary form-control test" id="id_resume" name="resume" type="file" />
               <div class="form-group">
            <button style="float:right;display: inline;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Submit
              </button> </div>
        </form>
```

and a post email controller form where the send mail is done

```
public function postconEmail(){

  $data = $this->input->post();
  $this->load->library('email');
  $config = array();
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.example.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@example.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 'xxx';
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from($data['from_email']);
    $this->email->to('info@example.com');
    $this->email->subject($data['subject']);
    $this->email->message($data['message']);
    $this->email->attach($data['resume']);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Email Sent');
      redirect(base_url());
    } else{
      show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
  }
```

The mail is going through but there is no file attached to the mail i am receiving.

I looked up google but am not able to get my hands on any posts regarding  this matter.

And over that I am new to php and Codeigniter 3 any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Please add your view file which have a form_open and action go to postconEmail()

Comment: updated @ImBS95

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You have to add attachment file path in attachment argument

Replace Your post email controller as per below

```
public function postconEmail(){
    $data = $this->input->post();
    $this->load->library('email');
    $config = array();
    $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
    $config['smtp_host'] = 'mail.example.com';
    $config['smtp_user'] = 'user@example.com';
    $config['smtp_pass'] = 'password';
    $config['smtp_port'] = 'xxx';
    $this->email->initialize($config);

    $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");

    $this->email->from($data['from_email']);
    $this->email->to('info@example.com');
    $this->email->subject($data['subject']);
    $this->email->message($data['message']);

    $resume_tmp_path = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'].'/'.$_FILES['resume']['name'];

    $this->email->attach($resume_tmp_path);
    if ($this->email->send()) {
      $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Email Sent');
      redirect(base_url());
    } else{
      show_error($this->email->print_debugger());
    }
  }
```

If This is not working then you refer this question it says You cannot attach file without upload your Server so first you have to upload file in your server and then pass `$this->email->attach(youy file path);` so your code definetely work.

**Refer This Question :** 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3628203/3377733

Comment: thanks a lot it worked like a charm...but the only problem is the uploaded file i am receiving is in .tmp extention any solution for that ?

Comment: i update my code you can pass your filename after tmp_name then it is ok and if not working then upload your file and get path and send in mail. hurray!