# Codeigniter sending email to multiple email ids, file attachment is not going with emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email to multiple users with an attachment through a form, In the form,I am selecting email id's and attaching a single file. Emails are going but without the file attached, while file is uploading in the given directory. I think there is some problem with the path, Please help.

```
class Email extends MY_Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('global_model');
        $this->load->library('email');     
        if(!$this->_is_logged_in('admin_id'))
        {
            _redirect('admin_login');
        }
    }

    public function send_newsletter()
    {
        $config = [
            'upload_path'   =>      './assets/email_documents',
            'allowed_types' =>      'jpg|gif|png|jpeg|doc|docx|pdf|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|txt',
            'max_size'      =>      '5120',
        ];
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->do_upload('filename');
        $data = $this->upload->data(); // To Upload the image
        $file_name = $data['file_name']."<br/>";
        $file_path = base_url("assets/email_documents/" . $data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext']);



         $lists = $this->input->post('lists');
         $subject = $this->input->post('subject');
         //$message = $this->input->post('message');

         $join_str1 = "subscribers.subscriber_list_id=lists.list_id";

         $subscribers =  
         $this->global_model
         ->join_2table('subscribers','lists', $join_str1,['subscriber_list_id'=>$lists,'subscriber_status'=>'Active']); 



        foreach($subscribers as $row) {

            $email_lists = $row['subscriber_email'];
            $random_key = $row['random_key'];   
            $message = $this->input->post('message').
            "<a href=\"http://example.com/crm_alazizi/unsubscribe/unsubscribe_me/{$random_key}\">Unsubscribe Here</a>";

            $from_email = 'support@example.com';
            $this->email->from($from_email, 'CRM ALAZIZI'); 
            $this->email->to($email_lists);
            $this->email->subject($subject); 
            $this->email->message($message); 
            $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
            $this->email->attach('/assets/email_documents/'.$file_name);
            $sendmail = $this->email->send();

        }                 
            //Send mail 
            if($sendmail) 
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Email sent successfull.');
                _redirect_pre();
            } 
            else 
            {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','Email sent Unsuccessfull,Please try again');
                _redirect_pre();
            }      
    }
```

Comment: why you have concated <br/> ?? Remove that and make sure that you get correct filename along with filename.

Comment: Kindly put the `temp_path` of image

Comment: $this->email->attach($data['full_path']); check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383672/code-igniter-attach-email

Comment: `$data['file_name']."<br/>"`. File names can't contain HTML markup. That's what you'd do if you wanted to _output_ the file _name_, not try to access the file itself. BTW I wouldn't have put that support@ email address into your question without obfuscating it. Unless you delete the question or ask the mods to remove it, it will be crawlable by spambots forever more (even editing the question doesn't help, since it will be visible in the revision history).

Comment: Also it's unclear why you create the $file_path variable, since you never use it. Was this intended to be the base path to the attachment? Mind you, since it will output a URL and not a file path, it likely won't be correct anyway.

Comment: Are you going to send a million emails when you get a million subscribers? Depends on whether it needs scalability though.

Answer (score 1):

long shot:

change

```
$this->email->attach('/assets/email_documents/'.$file_name);
```

to

```
$this->email->attach(base_url .'assets/email_documents/'.$file_name);
```

As you say the file uploads correctly, maybe the file name is wrong:

from

```
$file_name = $data['file_name']."<br/>";
$file_path = base_url("assets/email_documents/" . $data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext']);
```

to

```
$file_name = $data['raw_name'] . $data['file_ext'];
$file_path = base_url("assets/email_documents/" . $file_name);
```

If it gets downvoted I'll delete, I just tried quickly.