# send email with attach file saved in server folder | codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am try to send email with attach file saved in server folder , the email send successfully but the file not view inside the email sent

> how can I retrieve the path of file saved in server?

```
          $this->load->library('email');
         $this->load->helper('file');
         $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
         $this->email->from($fromEmail, $fromEmailName);
         $this->email->to($toEmail);
         $this->email->subject($emailSubject);

$message = '<p> confirm </p> <img src="cid:logo" width="80" height="80" />'; // here src id 

$file_name = "file.jpeg";

$file_url= base_url()."/uploads/".$file_name;

$this->email->attach($file_url , 'logo' , 'inline' ); // here when add the src id not work
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter sending email to multiple email ids, file attachment is not going with emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45939176/codeigniter-sending-email-to-multiple-email-ids-file-attachment-is-not-going-wi)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your file address may wrong. Chekc the file name again.

If that not working try something like this.

```
  $file_url= $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/uploads/".$file_name;
  $this->email->attach($file_url);
```

or else study answers for the following questions similar to your one.

[answer 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45945420/4156974)

Comment: the wrong in the path i know , but again your path is not work with me

Comment: is that "5.jpeg" your files name?

Comment: the ere when i put the src name and inline see here i will update my Q

Comment: echo the $file_url and check whether it can be opened in browser

Comment: like this is work ---- $message = '<p> confirm </p> <img src="'.base_url().'/uploads/'.$file_name.'" width="80" height="80" />';----- but i donot want like this , couse this the recevier have to click on view all email body to show the image , so i have to user embeded image